# Database redesigning to store identical items with different usage

Tags: database-design

I have the following table:

```
Product (Id, CategoryId, Description, Value)
```

One day ALL of the old products are no longer sold and new products arrive.
However, I want to keep the old ones for purchasing history.
I have thought of adding a field that can be used to distinguish the old from new and make this table:

```
Product (Id, CategoryId, Description, Value, Available)
```

OR

Use a new table:

```
ProductVersionTwo (Id, CategoryId, Description, Value)
```

The same strategy is going to be applied for table `ProductCategory` and any other tables that might be using `Product`.

I don't know how many times this change might happen, but surely they are going to be very rare.

What solution would you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with the first approach with a slight change. Since you don't know if you'll need this information any time later, I'd replace the `available` column with the timestamp columns `validFrom` and `validTo`. `validTo` would be `NULL` if it's the product which is now available. To not confuse your users I'd create a view `SELECT * /*except maybe validFrom and validTo*/ FROM Product WHERE validTo IS NULL;`

With your second approach you have no advantage except maybe a better performance in case you wouldn't index the first approach appropriately and there are really, really much products. Instead you just get ugly queries with `UNION` and an extra column you'd have to create on the fly to distinguish the product versions. Plus you'd have to store information somewhere about the different version tables. A year later you'll wonder what was special about version 2. And 3?

Another problem with the second approach might be joining to other tables in case you're working with autoincrementing columns. You'd have to start with the max(autoincrement) from the previous version table to not get confused when you're doing analysis with older products and so on. Bad idea in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would go with the first option. It is easier to do and when this change occurs again in the future, you just have to flag the old products as 'unavailable'.